# How to organize conditionally created gremlin query (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I am a beginner in gremlin with TinkerPop and have this query in JavaScript. It works fine. Since this question is not related to the query but rather how to structure it, so I don't think a graph is be needed for this.

This query solves two questions:

- What restaurant near me with a specific cuisine is the highest rated?
  -- set `cuisines`, `queryOrder`, `limit=1` and `restaurantFilter`
- Which restaurants are the ten highest-rated restaurants near me?
  -- set `limit=10` and `queryOrder`

```
// usuals
let dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(`ws://localhost:8182/gremlin`, {});
const graph = new Graph();
const __ = gremlin.process.statics;
const p = gremlin.process.P;
const order = gremlin.process.order;
const g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);


// limit for objects returned.
const limit: number | undefined = undefined;
// order on reviews
const queryOrder = order.desc;
// restaurant filters
const restaurantFilter = {location: "x"}

//26, 32
const cuisines = [26];
function convertObjectToGremlinPropertyFilter(
  data: Record<string, any>,
  g: gremlin.process.GraphTraversal
) {
  return Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    g.has(key, data[key]);
  });
}

async function init() {
  const result = g.V().hasLabel("restaurant");

  convertObjectToGremlinPropertyFilter(restaurantFilter, result);

  const reviewQuery = __.inE("review").has("value", p.gte(2));

  if (order) {
    reviewQuery.order().by("value", order.desc);
  }
  reviewQuery.valueMap().fold();

  if (cuisines.length) {
    console.log("Filtering cuisines");
    result.where(
      __.outE("serves")
        .inV()
        .hasLabel("cuisine")
        .hasId(p.within(...cuisines))
    );
  }

  result
    .project("restaurants", "reviews")
    .by(
      __.project("info", "cuisines")
        .by(__.valueMap(true))
        .by(
          __.outE("serves").unfold().inV().hasLabel("cuisine").valueMap().fold()
        )
    )
    .by(reviewQuery);

  if (limit) {
    result.limit(limit);
  }

  const dataRaw = await result.toList();

  await dc.close();

  const data = JSON.stringify(normalizeData(dataRaw as any), null, 2);
  fs.writeFileSync("./data.json", data);
}
```

For now, I've hardcoded the `limit`, `queryOrder`, and `cuisines` array. And creating the query on the condition applied to them.

As you can see, this query is kind of hard to maintain and interpret what it is doing. I've done the research and didn't find any resources related to structuring conditional queries. How can I structure these kinds of queries?

### Original Query:

```
   g.V()
    .hasLabel("restaurant")
    .has("location", "karachi")
    // Check for cuisines
    .where(
      __.outE("serves")
        .inV()
        .hasLabel("cuisine")
        .hasId(p.within(id1,id2))
    )
    // build the object
    .project("info", "cuisines", "reviews")
    .by(__.elementMap())
    .by(__.outE("serves").inV().hasLabel("cuisine").elementMap().fold())
    // Get reviews which are greater than 1 and order by highest review
    .by(
      __.inE("review")
        .has("value", p.gte(1))
        .order()
        .by("value", queryOrder)
        .valueMap(true)
        .fold()
    )
    .limit(10)
    .toList();
```

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: The approach you have taken, building up a query in a stepwise fashion, is quite reasonable and commonly done. Which parts of the query are you wanting to change or simplify?

Comment: I was wondering if there are some practices I am not following to make this better. I've come with this solution without seeing anyone doing it.

Comment: What would help, I was planning to do this, but would be great if you could, would be to edit the question to also show the complete query (assuming all pieces are present) as stand alone Gremlin. I followed the steps your code is doing and made a mental model of the query but it is easier to just look at it as a whole. We might then be able to trim it down a bit more easily. I tend to start with the query I need to build and then work backwards to code from there.

Comment: Sure, let me add that.